# Smart home Aqara API integration

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

Our task is to integrate our web application with the thermostat and temperature sensors.  We bought Aqara temperature sensors and Aqara hub, and they can be connected to the mobile Aqara application.  However, we cannot connect to them through HTTP API.

Also, for connection to the Alexa thermostat we also have the problems because we cannot enable the thermostat.  We do not the output thermostat device like Air Conditioner to connect, so we need to find some imitation. So far we are not successful.

Advice and Guidance are appreciated.

API integration Aqara Development

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can create a smart home skill without actual device. When you create a smart home skill, you enable Alexa to invoke your skill to fulfill a user request to control a smart home device. Smart home skills use the pre-built voice interaction model and Alexa defines the set of utterances for you. You can create an Alexa smart home skill for most device types. This is a good document to star with: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/steps-to-build-a-smart-home-skill.html.

Before you implement smart home skills, you should understand the components of a smart home skill and when to use them. You can learn Smart Home skill concept from https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/smart-home-skill-concepts.html.